# Does the Android Fingerprint API support externally connected USB fingerprint scanners?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, usb, android-fingerprint-api

I want to make an android app that easily connects to off-the-shelf USB fingerprint scanners. I am not sure if the android.hardware.fingerprint supports externally connected devices. Or is it only for internal scanner? Can anybody please confirm?

Edit: I would also like to know, would the USB connected fingerprint scanner work on devices that do not have inbuilt module, or on devices on older Android versions, i.e. 5.1 & below, since native API support has only been added from Android 6.0 onwards.

Guides/tutorials/links etc., anything will do. Please suggest something. Thanks.

[image: USB fingerprint scanner]

Comment: Yes, it does. The most popular example I can think of would be the Reliance Jio eKYC SIM card activation in Indian metros through USB fingerprint scanners connected to their phones.

Comment: @SajalNarang Thumbs up for the example. :)

Comment: @SajalNarang Jio eKYC Is using thier own application for detecting the external figureprint external device so they must be having their own sdk for that particular device what if the company of the that device is defferent then will it be able to  scan from the same api that google is providing for thier internal device authentication

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: No. In India, Morpho fingerprint scanners are very common (something like 1300 E3) as pictured above. I searched for long, the software support files for Android apps is not openly available on their own website. Probably they lock it down, maybe they have the paid licensing schema where only such companies have direct access to files & support.